# Java compatibility for serialized object read from changed class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a class of this form:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130605L;

    private Object fields[];

    // Methods, etc.
}
```

For some time this was ok, but now (for readability and maintenance) have been transformed to:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130605L;

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private Boolean fiedl3;

    // Methods, etc.
}
```

And the problem come when you tray to read old files with the new class version. If you use different serialVersionUID, aren't compatible. If you use the same serialVersionUID, I need to implement something to make it compatible. And this is my aproach, overwrite `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException`so I can check manually what version is the object in the file.

The problem again come in that I want to use `java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject();` so it automatically do its "magic" for next versions (in witch new fields will be optional). So I have something like:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130605L;

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private Boolean fiedl3;

    // Methods, etc.

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


        Object obj = in.readObject();

            if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] tmp = (Object[])obj;
            field1 = (String)obj[0];
            field2 = (String)obj[1];
            // ....
        } else {
            in.defaultReadObject();
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is that as I have already read part of the stream, the defaultReadObject method crash.

I have search for a Stream that let you read an object twice, but I don't found it. I also know that I can make the read totally manually, but then each time I add another field I will need to modify this (in `defaultReadObject`, as it write fields name, it can restore only the field that were read automatically).

So my question is ¿How can I make it?

Note: I only need that compatibility is for read old class object from new class and new class object from new class object. Also I have read other question but they only answer how to plan a good class to have backguard compatibility (I should have read it before :-( ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I have found is to maintain a reference to the old field. Note that you can set it as `transient` because then it will not be read, so you must carry it for ever.

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130605L;

    private Object fields[]; // So we can read it in old saved version.

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private Boolean fiedl3;

    // Methods, etc.

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {


        in.defaultReadObject();


        if (fields != null) {
            // If we have read an old version.
            field1 = (String)fields[0];
            field2 = (String)fields[1];
            field3 = (Boolean)fields[2];
            // ....

            // We set fields to null so no more space is waste than necessary.
            fields = null;
        }

    }
}
```